# HTML Vertical Slider Element

Tags: html, css, slider, vertical-alignment

hopefully a quick one - why is my slider element not orientating vertically?  What am I missing?

Thank you!

CSS

```
div.CRHslider{
-webkit-appearance: slider-vertical;
    data-orientation="vertical";
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="CRHslider">
Control Rod Height
<br>
0% <input type="range" name="ControlRodHeight" min="0" max="100" value="0" 
onchange="updateCRHSlider(this.value)" class="vertical" orient="vertical"/> 100%
</div>
```

Comment: show me code than i will check  ?

Comment: Hi Lalit, the code is included in my original question.  This isn't about the slider functionality (that is working fine), just the orientation.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```css
#CRHslider1 {
    -webkit-appearance: slider-vertical;
    data-orientation="vertical";
}
```

```html
<div id="CRHslider">
  Control Rod Height
  <br>
  0% <input type="range" name="CRHslider1" id="CRHslider1" min="0" max="100" value="0" onchange="updateCRHSlider(this.value)" class="vertical" orient="vertical"/> 100%
</div>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/david_black/3jot0pvx/

The reason your css isn't working is because it's matching the div instead of the input.

Comment: Hi David, thanks for your answer but I'm afraid I don't understand? I have two sliders stored in separate divs - if I change the CSS so it doesn't reference a div, how do I differentiate between them?  Can I refer to a slider id and orientate them that way? Thank you!

Comment: Yes you could assign IDs to both sliders. That would certainly work.